# How to load external CSS file for aurelia-dialog plugin?

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

I'm integrating the aurelia-dialog plugin into an Aurelia CLI project using TypeScript 2+.

I want to theme dialogs by replacing the default CSS the plugin uses with my own CSS coming from a SASS file, like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .plugin('aurelia-dialog', (config: DialogConfiguration) => {
            config.useDefaults();
            config.useCSS(aiDialogCss);
        });            

    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

The `aiDialogCss` variable has to be a string though, and I don't want to manually embed it in this code, I would prefer to load this CSS string from a separate CSS file that is compiled from SASS and bundled as per any other CSS file.

Is this possible using TypeScript and Aurelia CLI? I tried using `import aiDialogCss from "styles/ai-dialog.css!text"` but that doesn't compile.

Comment: looks like there was an interesting discussion on this topic on [github](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/273)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to have your custom css imported with  `<require from="./your-custom.css"></require>` in app.html
and passing empty string to `config.useCSS('');`